# Numbers: hotkeys to choose cells in formula edit mode

Tags: numbers

When I edit formulae in Numbers, is it possible to select nearby cells using the cursor keys?

For example, I might be editing cell C3, and set its formula to "=B2+C2". I would like to select cells B2 by hitting the <kbd>⬆︎</kbd> and then the <kbd>⬅︎</kbd>, to take the cursor from C3 to B2. I've tried hitting the keys, and using combinations of <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>, <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>, and <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. While editing the formula you can use the <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd> <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> keys with the arrow key's to move around and you can select multiple cells using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> as per normal.

Comment: When editing a formula, use the left/right arrow keys and the Shift key to select existing cell references, and move them around with these keyboard shortcuts. With nothing highlighted, holding the Option/Alt key will allow you to insert a new cell reference by navigating to it with the arrow keys.